# How to know in which module the function is declared in node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider two files

```
// sample.js

const test = () => {
    console.log("Testing Good.")
}

module.exports = { test }

// index.js

const sample = require("./sample")

getModuleForFunction(sample.test)

// I want the output to be 'sample.js'
```

How can I implement this `getModuleForFunction` method?

I cannot modify anything in the `sample.js` file.

Basically, given a function reference, we should be able to tell in which module the function is present.

Comment: You can try this one: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options

Comment: I don't have a string to resolve. I have a function and I have to generate a resolvable string out of it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  When you do `getModuleForFunction(sample.test)`, you're just passing a function reference to your function and that function reference doesn't have any accessible properties that say where it was defined.